# AWS Mobile Analytics event submit

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-mobile-analytics

I'm currently making use of the JS SDK of Amazon Mobile Analytics. Setup is working fine, but custom event logging doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting the proper response:

```
Object {eventType: "'iPhone'", timestamp: "2018-04-09T06:27:01.567Z", session: Object, version: "v2.0", attributes: "{'Name1':'Value1', 'Name2':'Value2'}"…}
attributes:"{'Name1':'Value1', 'Name2':'Value2'}"
eventType:"'iPhone'"
metrics:Object
session:Object
 id:"XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
 startTimestamp:"2018-04-09T06:26:54.683Z"
 timestamp:"2018-04-09T06:27:01.567Z"
version:"v2.0"
```

Even though the response is fine, this event is not showing up on the dashboard. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending to a valid platform?

From the docs: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-mobile-analytics-js

```
    platform : DEVICE_PLATFORM,            //Optional valid values: 'Android', 'iPhoneOS', 'WindowsPhone', 'Blackberry', 'Windows', 'MacOS', 'Linux'
```